# installing python-tabulate

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install tabulate in my python from terminal but I always receive error. the used command and resulting errors are as follows:

**Command**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-tabulate
```

**error**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-tabulate
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved by applying the following command before the commands mentioned in the question. Also, the following page helps in understanding the problem.
**command**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

**webpage**
[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an updated python version. Example pyhton3, just use the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tabulate
```